# i get an error stating local variables stringtext and textview2 need to be finalized? If i final them then they wont update if im correct...?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText stringtext; // final error here
        stringtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


        TextView textView2; // final error here
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        Button startprogram = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override

            public void onClick(View view){

                // Insert what you want the button to do here!
                setContentView(R.layout.helloworld);
            }
        };
        startprogram.setOnClickListener(listener);

        // this is button to check the inserted code
        Button checkbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkbutton);
        View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View view){
                //insert button command here

                textView2.setText(stringtext.getEditableText());


            }
        };



    }
```

i get an error stating local variables stringtext and textview2 need to be finalized? If i final them then they wont update if im correct...?

Comment: Please give the exact error message

Answer (score 2):

`final` just means that a variable's reference cannot be changed. The object state will still change correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If an anonymous inner class (e.g. your `onClickListeners`) references a local variable, that variable must be `final`.  This is because the anonymous inner class actually receives a *copy* of that variable, and Java doesn't want the original and the copy to get out of sync.

A primitive type that is marked as final (e.g. an `int` or a `double`) cannot change in value; once set, it's stuck.  However, a variable that refers to an object is exactly that: a reference (essentially the object's location in memory).

The *reference* cannot be changed to point to a new object, but the object's fields and method can be used as normal.